# What does this character (禅) mean?

Tags: translation

I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me what this means!

[image: Unknown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "zen" and I hope I do not have to explain what zen is in  just a few sentences.

Comment: To clarify for anyone who doesn't get it, it's "zen" as in the Buddhist concept.  Also, to the OP, for future reference, [direction translation requests are off-topic](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/29) for JL&U.